# Prevent Unpacked Usage of Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-web-store

My extension is proprietary licensed. I see some users download crx file from Chrome Store, extract it, modify it and run the extension as Unpacked which gives them ability to bypass paid functionality.

How can I prevent users to run local unpacked extension?

Answer (score 1):

This may not fully answer your question, but if you want to check if the app is running in unpacked mode  or from the store, you can check the "update_url" key of the manifest, which is not present in unpacked mode.

```
if (! chrome.runtime.getManifest().update_url) {
    console.log('UNPACKED - DEV MODE!')
    DEVMODE = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it can be deleted from source code by the individual that runs it local, right?

Comment: Yes, naturally. Obfuscation can make it more difficult.